# Iothub message routing to different azure storage blob

Tags: azure-iot-hub

we are trying to route the incoming message from iothub into another azure storage blob.
we already able to route the incoming message to our internal azure storage blob. Anyone has idea whether its possible to route the incoming message to another azure storage blob meaning we can write the message into the storage blob.

[iothub-messagerouting-to-internal-storage-blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmwXq.png)
i understand that it can access storage blob from same subscription.
but is it possible to access different storage blob from different subscription?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/createorupdate) to update a metadata of the Azure IoT Hub resource.

Example of the item in the *storageContainers* array:

```
     {
        "connectionString": "myStorageConnectionString",
        "containerName": "mycontainer",
        "fileNameFormat": "{iothub}/{partition}/{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}/{HH}/{mm}",
        "batchFrequencyInSeconds": 60,
        "maxChunkSizeInBytes": 104857600,
        "encoding": "json",
        "name": "mystorage"
      }
```

Note, that the Authorization Bearer token is required for GET/PUT requests. For test purpose, the token can be obtained for example from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apimanagementoperations/list) when you click on the *Try it*, see the Request Preview.

Comment: hi roman thank you for the response,
is that mean if we put conenctionString of the other azure storage subscription the iothub message route will directed to that way?
when i add new storage for message routing it said that : 
"Create a new container, or choose an existing one that shares a subscription with this IoT hub."

Comment: That's correct. The portal doesn't handle manually configuring the storage container, so using the ARM template it can be done. Create the *Free tier IoT Hub* and add the storage to the *storageContainers* array in the ARM template. Once you have a storage in the IoT Hub metadata, you can use a portal to create a route. Note, that the Free tier allows only one custom endpoint, so delete it via the portal its route and storage endpoint before using other one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need simultaneously work with 2 storage accounts from different subscriptions, it is possible, but not via built-in integration.

As a potential solution listen to the events of the original blob storage, trigger the Azure function, which will do the copy of the incoming file into another blob storage at another subscription via ConnectionString (or delete, or other action)

**Update**

In order to change the routing, as mentioned by @Roman Kiss, need to use the ARM templates.

See the [Iot Hub and message routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing-config-message-routing-RM-template#resources-iot-hub-and-message-routing)

You will need to make a template document. In order to make life easier, you can first export the existing ARM template, modify it, and reapply it.

To export, go to your IOThub->Export template->Download:
[image]

In the "routing"->"endpoints" section modify the file (perhaps other fields in a "storageContainers" object need to adjust to your current data. You may introduce new parameters in this ARM template and repoint items in "storageContainers" to the proper parameters):

```
 "storageContainers": [
       {
           "connectionString": 
           "<<<<<ConnectionStringToTheNewStorage>>>>>",
           "containerName": "[parameters('storageContainerName')]",
           "fileNameFormat": "{iothub}/{partition}/{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}/{HH}/{mm}",
           "batchFrequencyInSeconds": 100,
           "maxChunkSizeInBytes": 104857600,
           "encoding": "json",
           "name": "[parameters('storage_endpoint')]",
           "subscriptionId": "[parameters('subscriptionId')]",
           "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().Name]"
       }
   ]
```

Then [deploy the RM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing-config-message-routing-RM-template#deploy-the-rm-template)

---

In order not to mess up with your current IotHub and it's routing, you may create a test environment (as pointed by @Roman Kiss, create a free tier IotHub) to reproduce current infrastructure, and execute update via ARM template. Once you happy with result, do the same with your production infrastructure

Comment: hi anton, thank you for the response.
my only concern is that introducing new component (FA) will incur new cost since have 1.6 mil message per day and eventually will grow up at 6 mil iot message per day. do you happen to know another approach to route the message to another azure storage subscription ?